# Transform a website to wordpress template

Tags: html, wordpress

Some may find my question very stupid, but i'll still ask.  I have a website that i've developed. The website is only made of html, css and javascript files. I've used bootsrap framework.
 My problem is the following: 
 Is it possible to transform the website into wordpress template (or wordpress website)? 
if yes, what is the procedure to transform  static website into wordpress template (or wordpress website)? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: this video might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5ulK2e8P48

Answer (score 0):

it is possible, but not so easy, however it's not dificult. I recomend you follow this tutorial:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/responsive-wordpress-bootstrap-theme-tutorial

Or whaterver tutorial that you find. There is some rules that you need to follow.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: convert all html files in to php file, by changing the extension.

Step 2: Assign different template name all your pages.

Step 3: Login to admin panel-> create all pages and assign respective templates to them.

Step 4: create a style.css in theme directory and define template name there.

Step 5: add an index.php( if not there) in theme directory.

For more details please read here 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very easy to convert html template to wordpress. Please follow steps in given url.

[Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3EFMhl8n30)

[Click here](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/converting-html-sites-to-wordpress-sites)

Answer (score 0):

**WordPress templating**

**Step - 1**

Understand the template hierarchy

- https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

**Step - 2**

Start converting your html template to WordPress template

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

It's not a tough to study WordPress templating, explore and start developing. Try to follow WordPress Codex.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it Build custom template for each page.